Consolidating all sheets data into another work book
I have a Master file which contains 5 sheets names like SC1,SC2,SC3,SC4,SC5. I have to collate all these sheets data into my working file book based on the week commencing.
I am using the below formula by taking helper columns which gives my result. Is there any other approach?
=VSTACK(
FILTER(INDIRECT($D$3&D5),INDIRECT($D$3&E5)=$F$4),
FILTER(INDIRECT($D$3&D6),INDIRECT($D$3&E6)=$F$4),
FILTER(INDIRECT($D$3&D7),INDIRECT($D$3&E7)=$F$4),
FILTER(INDIRECT($D$3&D8),INDIRECT($D$3&E8)=$F$4),
FILTER(INDIRECT($D$3&D9),INDIRECT($D$3&E9)=$F$4))

[![Master file][1]][1]
https://i.sstatic.net/65aPGY6B.png
[![Working File][2]][2]
https://i.sstatic.net/trHpLJGy.png

You cannot embed image?

I am trying to add the same but I am failing @rachel

Maybe you can try using https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/ to convert some of your data into copiable markdown.

There is a thing called "3D reference": https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-3d-reference-formula/#:~:text=A%203D%20reference%20in%20Excel,to%20the%20Excel%20Consolidate%20feature.

You can use 3D reference to stack data from SC1 to SC5:
=VSTACK('SC1:SC3'!$A$2:$C$100)

To filter by week commencing date, you can use FILTER and LET:
=LET(stacked,VSTACK('SC1:SC3'!$A$2:$C$12),dates,TAKE(stacked,,1),FILTER(stacked,dates="wc 16th Jun 2024",""))



@nkalvi I think FILTER will filter out blank cells anyway. But yes, named range is good ideal.

Hi, I deleted my comment as it wasn't contributing much.
